# Why are two dialog boxes popping up when I used angularjs-popup.js plugin?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

As the following code , The web shows two dialog,why?

```
Popup.alert('hello world', function () {
    console.log('ok');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

change the version of angularjs to 1.1.5 and work done.